# How to Search XML Block and Delete the same

Tags: shell, scripting, regular-expression, xml, xmlstarlet

This is my XML.

```
<configGroup>
<type>SERVER_CONFIG</type>
  <configProperty id="Server48">
    <configProperty>
        <name>Server Name</name>
        <value>oaea_server1</value>
        <itemMetadata>
            <dataType>STRING</dataType>
            <scope>READ_ONLY</scope>
        </itemMetadata>
    </configProperty>
    <configProperty>
        <name>Listen Address</name>
        <value>server.com</value>
        <itemMetadata>
            <dataType>STRING</dataType>
            <scope>READ_WRITE</scope>
        </itemMetadata>
    </configProperty>
    <configProperty>
        <name>Listen Port</name>
        <value>6851</value>
        <itemMetadata>
            <dataType>INTEGER</dataType>
            <scope>READ_WRITE</scope>
        </itemMetadata>
    </configProperty>
</configProperty>
<configProperty id="Server6">
    <configProperty>
        <name>Server Name</name>
        <value>oacore_server2</value>
        <itemMetadata>
            <dataType>STRING</dataType>
            <scope>READ_ONLY</scope>
        </itemMetadata>
    </configProperty>
    <configProperty>
        <name>Listen Address</name>
        <value>server.com</value>
        <itemMetadata>
            <dataType>STRING</dataType>
            <scope>READ_WRITE</scope>
        </itemMetadata>
    </configProperty>
    <configProperty>
        <name>Listen Port</name>
        <value>7251</value>
        <itemMetadata>
            <dataType>INTEGER</dataType>
            <scope>READ_WRITE</scope>
        </itemMetadata>
    </configProperty>
</configProperty>

</configGroup>
```

XML contains lot of other type of server and my requirement is to delete all the servers which matches oaea_server.

Output should grep for below and delete the same from new XML

```
<configProperty id="Server48">
    <configProperty>
        <name>Server Name</name>
        <value>oaea_server1</value>
        <itemMetadata>
            <dataType>STRING</dataType>
            <scope>READ_ONLY</scope>
        </itemMetadata>
    </configProperty>
    <configProperty>
        <name>Listen Address</name>
        <value>server.com</value>
        <itemMetadata>
            <dataType>STRING</dataType>
            <scope>READ_WRITE</scope>
        </itemMetadata>
    </configProperty>
    <configProperty>
        <name>Listen Port</name>
        <value>6851</value>
        <itemMetadata>
            <dataType>INTEGER</dataType>
            <scope>READ_WRITE</scope>
        </itemMetadata>
    </configProperty>
</configProperty>
```

I have tried using grep and it works also but then I have hardcoded the lines before and after

grep -B 3 -n -A 22 oaea_server

But I know this is not the correct way as there could be changes in the xml any time and the automated script will fail.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `xmlstarlet` this should do the trick with properly formed `xml`

```
xmlstarlet ed -d "//configProperty[.//value[contains(string(), 'oaea_server')]]" file1
```

Output has Server48 removed

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configGroup>
  <type>SERVER_CONFIG</type>
  <configProperty id="Server6">
    <configProperty>
      <name>Server Name</name>
      <value>oacore_server2</value>
      <itemMetadata>
        <dataType>STRING</dataType>
        <scope>READ_ONLY</scope>
      </itemMetadata>
    </configProperty>
    <configProperty>
      <name>Listen Address</name>
      <value>server.com</value>
      <itemMetadata>
        <dataType>STRING</dataType>
        <scope>READ_WRITE</scope>
      </itemMetadata>
    </configProperty>
    <configProperty>
      <name>Listen Port</name>
      <value>7251</value>
      <itemMetadata>
        <dataType>INTEGER</dataType>
        <scope>READ_WRITE</scope>
      </itemMetadata>
    </configProperty>
  </configProperty>
</configGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks..the same worked.